# Anyone have any idea how Humhub encrypts the password?

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, humhub

I am new to Humhub and coding. Anyone have any idea how humhub encrypts the password? I have been failing to create an encryption function in PHP for my subdomains to use the same database that I created when I installed Humhub. I seriously do not get how this works..
https://github.com/humhub/humhub/blob/master/protected/humhub/modules/user/models/Password.php#L43

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes late. But for everyone looking for a solution, this is how Humhub encrypts the password:

1. Take the password string, let's say is: dummy.
2. Generate a uuid string and concatenates to password: dummy889e9f96-91f6-45d2-bc3b-ab8d80ea6311
3. Encrypt this with whirlpool algorithm: whirlpool(dummy889e9f96-91f6-45d2-bc3b-ab8d80ea6311) = *hash1*
4. Encrypt the string in the preceding step with sha512 algorithm: sha512(hash1) = encrypt_password.
5. This encrypt_password will be on the *password* field in the **user_password** database. Also you need the uuid from 2 to the field *salt* in the **user_password** table.

Al of this is using **sha512-whirlpool** method

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to fill the user database of HumHub with users and passwords by VBScript, but didn't found a solution for a whirlpool encryption, but as I found in the source code, HumHub also supports SHA512.

The passwords are stored in the table user_password. Put "sha512" in the column algorythm. Put a GUID in the salt column.

```
Function CreateGUID
    Dim TypeLib
    Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
    CreateGUID = LCase(Mid(TypeLib.Guid, 2, 36))
End Function
```

Then add the salt to the password [Hash(Passwort & Salt)] and generate a Hash with the following function:

```
Function Hash(param)
    crypt.HashAlgorithm = "sha512"
    crypt.EncodingMode = "hex"
    hash = LCase(crypt.HashStringENC(param))
End Function
```

Put this hash in the password column.

In the following tables also a row has to be inserted that a user can successfully log on to HumHub:

```
user
user_password
group_user
space_membership
profile
contentcontainer
```